# Facebook logout does not remove the user completerly in my app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the facebook_sdk that I am using to authenticate facebook users on my app. Everything is fine but when the user is logged out for facebook he is logged out but his information still is on my application . So I want to kill session by the time he logged out. So Can you help me this. I have seen many posts related But didn't find correct answer to my case.

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to kill session by the time he logged out.

Give a `redirect_uri` parameter when creating your logout URL, and put a script there that calls `session_destroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK does not kill session in my application, so I edited the method **getLogoutUrl** in base_facebook.php and now It is fine.

```
public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
  session_destroy();
    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'logout.php',
      array_merge(array(
        'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
        'access_token' => $this->getUserAccessToken(),
      ), $params)
    );
  }
```